# Can apps control Accessibility settings directly?

Tags: ios, accessibility

For example I want to create a UIButton to control invert color. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, there is no **public** API to do that, it is outside your app sandbox.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I saw some apps able to control Brightness.

Comment: Yes there is a public API for screen brightness `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: 1.0];` but unfortunately there is not for inverting color.

Comment: You can check the doc for UIScreen class from: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/overscanCompensation